# How to exclude strings in grep command?

Tags: linux

I have an array which contains list of strings.

Example: array = ("Sample","Test","Check").

I need to pass this to grep command to exclude these string while getting results.
So, In the output I should not have ("Sample","Test","Check") terms.
Please help me.

Comment: grep version - grep (GNU grep) 2.20, 
shell  - /bin/csh,   I have a text file which contains list of files. I am doing grep for that file, grep '*.xml'  <file-name> , from that list I want to exclude some files.

Comment: sample.txt is the source file, it has one.xml, two.xml,three.xml, test.xml, check.xml. So from this list I dont want test.xml and check.xml file names and this exclude list will be a dynamic list.

Comment: The array you maintained is in `bash` shell context (or) `csh` shell context?

Comment: I am going to run this grep command in perl. array will be  available in perl.

Comment: You're almost done: `grep -v -E '(Sample|Test|Check)' ...`

Answer (score 1):

It can be done the following way:

```
grep -v -e string_to_exclude_1 -e string_to_exclude_2 file_name
```

For example, the following command excludes check.xml and test.xml from a file named sample.txt

```
grep -v -e check -e test sample.txt
```

sample.txt contains the following:

```
one.xml
two.xml
three.xml
test.xml
check.xml
```